# Bash script behaving different than when manually executing commands into remote server

Tags: bash, npm

I have a remote server and I can `ssh` into it and when I execute `npm install` it works just fine. I can see that it's installed by calling `which npm` and i see:

`/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v15.11.0/bin/npm`

Great.

However, when I do this via a bash script, it says

`bash: line 1: npm: command not found`

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh he-int 'npm install'
```

Why the discrepancy between the two ? It's the same commands...

Comment: _I can see that it's installed by calling which npm _  : Can you see this also on the remote side? i.e. `ssh he-int which npm`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe npm is added to your `PATH` in one of the login scripts (.bashrc, .profile, etc). I especially think this is true because the `npm` path indicates you are using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage your npm environment. There may be a call to `nvm` to add npm to the path in one of those login scripts.

When you run an ssh command like your second command, it doesn't run as a login shell, so it doesn't run the login scripts. You can either:

1. Try and force it to run as a login shell (`ssh -t` maybe? not sure).
2. Try to initialize your npm environment inside your script, probably by calling nvm.

Answer (score 0):

`npm` may not be in the PATH of the user you're sshing in as using the bash script.

Use this to see what's in your PATH variable:

`ssh he-int 'echo $PATH'`

You can also just try to use the path directly and see if it works.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ssh he-int '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v15.11.0/bin/npm install'
```